# What are alternatives to Java Executor to convert sequential program into program leveraging parallel execution?

Tags: java, executor

I have an existing logic which looks like this:

1. Input Identifiers (minimum 1 value maximum n values can be entered together).
2. Iterate over these identifiers 1 through N and retrieve data corresponding to them and perform some calculations (Method to retrieve data and calculations are same and can be parameterized to retrieve for passed variable).
3. Once these values are retrieved for all passed identifiers form arrays like 
   Identifier 1 : [Value a, Value b, Value c]
   Identifier 2 : [Value d, Value e, Value f]
   ...
   Identifier 1 : [Value x, Value y, Value z]
4. Once we have all the values identified in Step 3, create a cartesian product of all possible combinations of values for Identifiers 1,2, ... n and run comparison logic to come up with the best solution which could be like
   Identifier 1 - a, Identifier b, Identifier c.

Since this is sequential it takes time and I was hoping to break it down as follows:

I have an existing logic which looks like this:

1. Input Identifiers (minimum 1 value maximum n values can be entered together).
2. Instead of iterating over identifiers sequentially, I could do it parallelly.
3. Once these values are retrieved for all passed identifiers form arrays like

   - Identifier 1 : [Value a, Value b, Value c]
   - Identifier 2 : [Value d, Value e, Value f]
   - ...
   - Identifier 1 : [Value x, Value y, Value z]
4. Once we have all the values identified in Step 3,  separate the candidates for comparison in several groups and run the comparison logic on them parallelly let's say I divide them into 3 groups with total 3 identifiers. 
   Ex:

   - Group 1:
     Candidate 1: Identifier  1 - Value a, Identifier  2 - Value d, Identifier  n - Value x.
     Candidate 2: Identifier  1 - Value a, Identifier  2 - Value e, Identifier  n - Value y.
     Candidate 3: Identifier  1 - Value a, Identifier  2 - Value e, Identifier  n - Value z.
   - Group 2:
     Candidate 1: Identifier  1 - Value b, Identifier  2 - Value d, Identifier  n - Value x.
     Candidate 2: Identifier  1 - Value b, Identifier  2 - Value e, Identifier  n - Value y.
     Candidate 3: Identifier  1 - Value b, Identifier  2 - Value e, Identifier  n - Value z.

and so on.

I want to run comparison logic on these groups in parallel and come up with the best solution for each group and then run comparison logic again on results from the first iteration.

The idea is to drastically reduce computation times by executing parallelly.

One of the options I have been evaluating is using Executor Framework from Java to run these tasks in parallel.

Are there other options, that I can consider. Are there any standard solutions to the problem like this.

Comment: Why not use a parallel stream?

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian, I will run a test.